# Sending and receiving an image file C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, image

I have been struggling for a while now to send an image file over sockets. I believe I am very close, but I haven't gotten it yet. I am trying to send the image from the server to the client.

Here is my server code:

```
//Init listener
listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 550));

//Start listening for connections
listener.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection");
s = listener.AcceptSocket();
//If we reach here, we have a connection
Console.WriteLine("Connected");
//Get the screenshot and apply it to our memory stream
img = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
imgG = Graphics.FromImage(img);
imgG.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
img.Save("sc.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
//Convert image to byte array, and then send it
byte[] byteArray = ms.ToArray();
s.Send(byteArray);
s.Close();
Console.Read();
```

Here is my client code:

```
client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IPBox.Text), 550));
s = client.Client;
buffer = new byte[100000];
s.Receive(buffer);
ms.Read(buffer, 0, 100000);
img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
imgContainer.Image = (Image)img;
```

I think I am very close, but I might be far off. I am new to networking, and require help please. Thanks A lot.

Comment: Do you have a question, or are you just sharing this piece of information with us? (meant as a half-joke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your client, you are assuming that you received 100000 bytes from the server, and you're putting all 100000 bytes into the memory stream.

There is a great sample on the MSDN page for [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) which shows receiving from a TcpClient by using the underlying NetworkStream.  Also, you will want to keep track of how many bytes you actually received (this is the return value from the [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) function).  Finally, you'll want to keep reading until there is no more data to be read from the host.  If your image is larger than your buffer, then you'll only have a partial image also.  The sample on the linked page for [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) shows continually reading from the stream while there is data available.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am sure I will be able to get it working now :D.