# Sending/Receiving Image over TCP Socket in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to Send the image to the Client which is connected to my TCP Listner (Server). I am successfully sending and receiving text over Network but I am unable to send the picture to the client from my server. I want to Dislpay the picture in PictureBox placed in the Client Window. 
Here is a Code I am using to Send and Receive text **BUT NOT PICTURE**

**SERVER:**

RECEIVER:

```
void TListner()
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ipendp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
            TcpListener tl = new TcpListener(ipendp);
            tl.Start();
            Socket s1 = tl.AcceptSocket(); ;
            NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(s1);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);

            while (true)
            {
                    textBox1.Text = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }
```

SENDER:

```
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        sw.Write("TEST STRING");
        sw.Flush();
```

CLIENT:

RECEIVER:

```
    void TCP_CLIENT()
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ipendp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
            TcpClient tcpc = new TcpClient();
            tcpc.Connect(ipendp);
            NetworkStream ns = tcpc.GetStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
            while (true)
            {
                textBox1.Text = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

I want to display the picture in a PictureBox named **PBox1** in Client Window.

Comment: Try the answers given in these links


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811760/sending-and-receiving-an-image-file-c



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789294/tcp-client-server-image-transfer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're find to send and receive text because you're using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`. Those deal with text. You haven't actually shown the code you're *trying* to use for sending pictures, but fundamentally you *mustn't* use `Reader`/`Writer` unless you're performing some sort of extra encoding first (e.g. base64).

Also, unless you're going to close the writing socket immediately after sending, you should probably write the data length (e.g. as 4 bytes) before the data so that the receiving socket knows how much it needs to receive.