# Send image using TCP Socket Client App in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, base64, tcpclient

I'm trying to develop a simple TCP Client Application for Windows Phone.

On the server side, I'm using a simple C# Server Application which accepts the connection and then saves the file.

I saw an example on MSDN (for the client app, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx). 
But it only sends strings and I want to send files (pictures) from the client to the picture.

This is a server side code snippet which accepts the file sent from the client:

```
if (Listener.Pending())
                {
                    client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    netstream = client.GetStream();
                    Status = "Connected to a client\n";
                    result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);

                    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        string SaveFileName = string.Empty;
                        SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
                        DialogSave.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
                        DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
                        DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";

                        DialogSave.FileName = "sample.txt";
                        if (DialogSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            SaveFileName = DialogSave.FileName;
                        if (SaveFileName != string.Empty)
                        {
                            int totalrecbytes = 0;
                            FileStream Fs = new FileStream(SaveFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                            while ((RecBytes = netstream.Read(RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);
                                totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
                            }
                            Fs.Close();
                        }
                        netstream.Close();
                        client.Close();
                    }
                }
```

Now, the problem that I'm facing is that when I send the string from the phone, the server successfully acknowledges the connection and prompts to save the file. But, when I save the file and open it, the file is blank.

To check if the server is working properly, I made a simple C# client app (on Windows, not phone) and sent a file using that. And, it was saved successfully with all the contents intact.

Please help me.

Problems:
First, the string sent by the phone is acknowledged by the server but cannot be saved to a file.
Second, how to send an image from the phone (client)?

I thought of converting the image into base64 string and then sending the string to the server.
But, I don't know how to convert an image to a base64 string on Windows Phone.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look it this, may be this is helpful for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106187/sending-receiving-image-over-tcp-socket-in-c-sharp

Comment: Actually, I need a Windows Phone specific solution, and that is the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly write all of this yourself but have you possibly considered using a library to help save time? If so then checkout [networkcomms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net/), in particular a tutorial on sending non-primitive objects, using an image in the example, [here](http://www.networkcomms.net/custom-objects/#nonprimitive_types).

Disclaimer: I'm a developer for this library.

Answer (score 0):

Convert imageStream into memory Stream. Then convert to byte then to Base 64.

```
Stream imgStream = readImgFromFile(filename);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imgStream);
byte[] result = memoryStream.ToArray();
base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(result);
```